# R Function Slow, Looking to Increase Speed/Performance

Tags: r

I've built a prediction function in R, but when I run it's very slow, and I'm only using a sample of 1% of the data I'll be using in production.  The function is intended to predict the next word given a series of ngrams (two-word, three-word, or four-word combinations - created from my corpus).

I pass the words to the function, for example "i can", and the series of three-word combinations.  The output ranked in order decreasing would be "i can read",  count of 4.

Here is the two-word ngram passed is a matrix, the dim and example data from position 100.

```
 dim(bigram_index)
 [1] 46201  3 
 bigram_index[,1][100]
 [1] "abandon"
 bigram_index[,2][100]
 [1] "contemporary"
 bigram_index[,3][100]
 [1] "1"
```

Here is the prediction function:

```
predict.next.word <- function(word, ng_matrix){
ngram_df <- data.frame(predicted=character(), count = numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    col_ng_matrix <- nrow(bigram_index)
if(ncol(ng_matrix)==3){
        for (i in 1:col_ng_matrix){
        first_word <- ng_matrix[,1][i]
        second_word <- ng_matrix[,2][i]
        count_word <- ng_matrix[,3][i]
        if (word[1] == first_word && !is.na(first_word)){
            matched_factor <- structure(c(second_word, count_word), .Names = c("predicted", "count"))
            ngram_df[i,] <- as.list(matched_factor)
            }
        }  
    }  else if(ncol(ng_matrix)==4){
        for (i in 1:col_ng_matrix){
            first_word <- ng_matrix[,1][i]
            second_word <- ng_matrix[,2][i]
            third_word <- ng_matrix[,3][i]
            count_word <- ng_matrix[,4][i]
            if (word[1] == first_word && !is.na(first_word) && word[2] == second_word && !is.na(second_word)){
                matched_factor <- structure(c(third_word, count_word), .Names = c("predicted", "count"))
                ngram_df[i,] <- as.list(matched_factor)
                } 
            } 
        }  else if(ncol(ng_matrix)==5){
        for (i in 1:col_ng_matrix){
                first_word <- ng_matrix[,1][i]
                second_word <- ng_matrix[,2][i]
                third_word <- ng_matrix[,3][i]
                fourth_word <- ng_matrix[,4][i]
                count_word <- ng_matrix[,5][i]
                if (word[1] == first_word && !is.na(first_word) && word[2] == second_word 
                    && !is.na(second_word) && word[3] == third_word && !is.na(third_word)){
                    ngram_df[i,] <- as.list(matched_factor)
                    } 
                } 
            }
ngram_df <- transform(ngram_df, count = as.numeric(count))
return (ngram_df[order(ngram_df$count, decreasing = TRUE),])  
}
```

Using the smallest ngram (only two-word) here is the time results:

```
system.time(predict.next.word(c("abandon"), bigram_index))
user  system elapsed 
92.125  59.395 152.149
```

Again, the ngram passed again is only 1% of production data, and when I get into three and four-word, it takes much longer.  Please provide your insight on how to improve this function's speed.

Comment: vectorize. i haven't read closely but I smell "too many `for` loops."

Comment: I vectorized the conditional statement and it fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through columns, I would writing a function that performs the key actions of the `for()` loop, and use `apply()` (with `MARGIN=2` for columns, 1 for rows; I think you'll be using latter) to apply that function to each column (`FUN=` argument set equal to your function). Depending on the output format, apply might not be suitable. At that point you could look into `plyr` package, `dplyr`, or, my favorite (but somewhat of a learning curve, as is `dplyr`) the `data.table` package.

In general, take a look at Hadley's book chapter on the topic: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html

Currently, your code doesn't take advantage of the fact that so-call "vectorized" R code performs loops in C, making them much faster (forgive me if this description is technically incorrect; just getting the idea across).

For a more specific example, it might be helpful to see input (use `dput(data)`) and desired output. Then I'd have an easier time digesting what you want your function to accomplish.

Some general points that could help, at least a little:

1. You do `ncol(ng_matrix)` several times; instead, do `nc.ngm < - ncol(ng_matrix)` once at the start. Savings will be minimal, but the idea still useful.
2. Instead of defining `first_word` second, etc., just do something like `words <- ng_matrix[i,]`. Then use the previously-mentioned object to get the `count_word` by doing `count_word <- words[nc.ngm]` and get the other words as `numbered_words <- words[nc.ngm]`. To compare the `word` object elements to the `words` elements, you could even make use of `mapply` to get your logic. Again, this is all a little hard to follow without an example. But in general, do things "in bulk" (vectorize).